# Tabulator: When clicking small image show original image in full screen

Tags: tabulator

I need to build a table with some thumbnails images inside and when clicking on them, show the image in original size in full screen using some type of lightbox. Is it possible to do this using the Tabulator? I didn't find any examples or questions about it.

[image: Example of a table with an image]

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

See [Html Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/format#format-builtin)

```js
    const tabledata1 = [
        {image: "<img style='width: 20px;height: 20px' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581488066397-c5951361126a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>"},
        {image: "<img style='width: 20px;height: 20px' src='https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581488066397-c5951361126a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60'>"}
    ];



    const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
        height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
        data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
        layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
        columns: [ //Define Table Columns
            {title: "image", field: "image", formatter:"html"}
        ]
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabulator is only responsible for creating tables, it will not build light boxes for you, you would need to use a separate library for that.

in terms of handling click events, you could look at using the ***cellClick*** or ***rowClick*** events to trigger a lightbox library to open:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowClick:function(e, row){
        //e - the click event object
        //row - row component

        //trigger a lightbox library
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //View Detail
      {title:"Image", field:"imageurl",formatter:"image", formatterParams:{height:"50px",width:"50px"},cellClick:function(e, cell){
                                
                                
                 var getimageurl = cell.getRow().getData().imageurl
                 var getname= cell.getRow().getData().name
                 var getdes= cell.getRow().getData().des     

                 console.log(getimageurl)        

                if (typeof getimageurl !== 'undefined' && getimageurl) {

                  const lightbox = GLightbox({
                                        touchNavigation: true,
                                        loop: true,
                                        autoplayVideos: true
                                            });

                   const myGallery = GLightbox({

                                              elements: [
                                                  {
                                                      'href': getimageurl,
                                                      'type': 'image',
                                                      'title': getname,
                                                      'description': getdes,
                                                  },
                                                  {
                                                      'content': document.getElementById('inline-example') // this will append a node inside the slide
                                                  },
                                              ],
                                              autoplayVideos: true,
                                          });
                              myGallery.open();
                }

                  }},
```

Comment: Use library https://biati-digital.github.io/glightbox/# for lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is indeed possible to achieve this using Tabulator along with the GLightbox library for the lightbox functionality. Tabulator allows you to create a table with thumbnail images inside each cell. When a user clicks on a thumbnail image, the corresponding full-size image can be displayed in a lightbox using GLightbox.

Here's how you can achieve this:

1. First, make sure to include the required CSS and JavaScript
   dependencies for Tabulator and GLightbox in your HTML code.
2. Create a div element with a unique ID where you want the table to be displayed.
3. Use JavaScript to initialize the Tabulator table and configure it to display thumbnail images. Set up the cellClick event to open the full-size image in the GLightbox when a thumbnail image is clicked.

```js
const glightbox = GLightbox({
  openEffect: "zoom",
  closeEffect: "fade",
  zoomable: true,
});

const tabledata1 = [
    {image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581488066397-c5951361126a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"},
    {image: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1581488066397-c5951361126a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"}
];

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data: tabledata1, //assign data to table
    layout: "fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns: [ //Define Table Columns
        {title: "image", field: "image", formatter:"image", formatterParams:ImgParamLookup,            cellClick:function(e, cell){ // event is triggered when a user left clicks on the cell.
              glightbox.setElements([
                {
                  'href': cell.getValue(),
                  'type': 'image'
                },
              ]);
              glightbox.open();
          }},
    ]
});

function ImgParamLookup(cell) {
  return {
    height: "100px",
    width: "100px",
    background: "#fff",
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/css/glightbox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/glightbox/3.2.0/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```

With this setup, you'll be able to build a table with thumbnail images inside and achieve the desired behavior of opening the full-size image in a lightbox when the thumbnails are clicked. This combination of Tabulator and GLightbox provides an effective solution for displaying images in a table format while offering a seamless user experience for viewing them in full-screen mode.

Feel free to customize the URLs, sizes, and styles according to your specific requirements.